# Prevent Android USB Host (OTG) from suspend

Tags: android, usb, host

I'm working on a USB gadget which is intended to be used with USB Host (OTG) enabled Android devices. My gadget consumes a fair amount of power (~30-40mA) and is completely powered by the host. I've been able to power and control it with my Motorola Xoom (Android version 3.2) but I got one **big** problem:

Every time the screen goes off, the USB host sends a **suspend** command which indicates to reduce power consumption to < 2.5mA! When the screen goes/is on USB gets resumed to normal power.

Since I **absolutely need** to have 'full power' all the time, please help me and post some hints how I could prevent the USB host to go to suspend mode. I tried a full wake lock, but it didn't help :(

Thank you in advance,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Use a second 5v power source; just make sure to tie the negative to the USB.